# Transfer files server to server

Tags: php, file, shell, file-transfer

I need to transfer one account to a different server. The big problem is: one have Cpanel (Good!) and other have Custom Branded Panel (Bad =(). So, I thinked: How about to transfer with PHP? (how? Don't know)

I know server support exec, and I have Jailsshell (SSH), but, wget are disabled. Dont know about others restrictions. Ideas?

I have tried this:

```
function ftp($host, $username, $password, $local, $remote) {
    $execTime = 7000;
    ini_set('max_execution_time', $execTime);
    set_time_limit($execTime);

    $c = ftp_connect($host);
    ftp_set_option($c, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, $execTime);
    ftp_login($c, $username, $password) or die("Can't login");

    ftp_get($c, $local, $remote, FTP_ASCII);

    ftp_close($c) or die("Can't close");
}
```

But get request timeout..

Comment: did you think to zip everything, and create a php file with file_get_contents() & file_put_contents() ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV does not work. See my updated question.

Comment: try on the top of your code this: ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

Answer (score 0):

Can you access scp from exec? It would allow for copying over the file structure from one host to another.

Comment: if you have ssh access on atleast one of the hosts and the other has access to scp you could push or pull the data across. its easiest with one file so if you can tar it up first that would be easier.

scp [[user@]host1:]file1 [[user@]host2:]file2

That would be how you use it in basic terms

Answer (score 0):

First I would login through ssh or telnet to the server with the website. Here are the commands I would type:

```
cd /home/somepath/to/yourwebsite/public_html 
tar -cvf sitepack.tar ./
```

Once that is finished I would goto your new server and login through telnet and ssh. Here I would type:

```
cd /home/somepath/to/yourwebsite/public_html 
wget yourdomain.com/sitepack.tar 
tar -xvf sitepack.tar
```

At this point I would check to make sure the correct owner and group are on your files you just unpacked. You can check to see what they are by typing:

```
ls -la
```

If the owner or group is wrong you can type this to fix all the files:

```
chown -R owner.group ./
```

owner.group should be replaced with the owner name you want and the group name you want. This will recursively go through all your files and directories and changed them to the correct owner and group.

Comment: On the new box?... then just download the tar file via ftp and upload it to the new server and do tar -xvf sitepack.tar

Comment: I want only server -> server connections